# How to print(log) request xml body which is getting passed from java application to soap web service

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl2java

I would like to print xml body which is getting passed from my web service client to soap web service deployed on some other server.
The problem is that I only have wsdl file with me but no service end point is available to do the end to end testing so I wanted to ensure that request xml is getting passed correctly from my end correctly. Please let me know how can I print this.

Comment: This seems to be already answered in below post-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175002/getting-raw-xml-soap-response-on-client-side-using-adb-stubs-created-by-axis2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String requestXML=_call.getMessageContext().getRequestMessage().getSOAPPartAsString();

String responseXML=_call.getMessageContext().getResponseMessage().getSOAPPartAsString();